# Maximization problem with preferences on variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, integer-programming, constraint, logical-constraints

Consider the following trivial, theoretical model:

$$
\max x+2y+3z \qquad s.t.
$$
$$
x \leq b_x
$$
$$
y \leq b_y
$$
$$
z \leq b_z
$$
$$
x+y+z = 1
$$
$$
x,y,z \in \{0, 1\}
$$

and $b_x$, $b_y$ and $b_z$ integer, non-negative parameters. Whenever the parameter $b_z \geq 1$ the trivial solution would be $z=1, x=y=0$. Let us assume I have hypotethical reasons to "prefer" $x$ over $z$, and $z$ over $y$; say, when $b_x$, $b_y$ and $b_z$ are greater/equal 1, return $x=1, y=z=0$ as solution. In other words, **I would maximize the objective function under a "preference constraint" on variables. Is it possible to express such a constraint as a MIP/MILP?**

For example, imposing $z \leq x$ and $y \leq z$ would do the trick when both $b_x$ and $b_z$ are greater/equal 1, but when $b_x = 0$, $b_z \geq 1$ and $b_y \geq 1$ it would return $x=y=z=0$, whereas the optimal solution for me according to my preference would be $z=1, x=y=0$. Similarly, with $b_x = b_z = 0$ and $b_y\geq 1$ the optimal solution from solving the problem would be again $x=y=z=0$ whereas what I want according to my preference would be $y=1, x=z=0$. So my attempt $z \leq x$ and $y \leq z$  clearly does not work.

I am looking for a generalizable solution for any number of variables and any preference, not just for a solution to this specific case.

Comment: Why not express the preferences in the objective function?

Comment: @RobPratt you mean changing the objective completely or adding a term to the current objective? I want to maximize the objective $x+2y+3z$ (let's say it represents a profit) under the constraint that, when possible, $x$ should be selected before $z$.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a primary objective of maximizing preference and a secondary objective of maximizing profit. You might consider the lexicographic approach to this multiobjective problem.

Answer (score 1):

How is this following constraint
Either
$b_z + y \le b_x+z +b_y\le x + b_z +yb_y$
Or let's break it
$b_x+z \le x + b_z$
$b_z + y \le z +b_y $

Comment: It does not seems to work. When $b_x = b_z = 0$ and $b_y = m$ it gives $0+y \leq 0 + 0 + m \leq 0 + 0$, that is $y\leq m \leq 0$. I am looking for a general solution, not just a solution to this specific example. Thanks.

Comment: Ok let me break it up then